# Providing an implementation for a pure virtual method in an abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class

What is the effect of providing an implementation for a method declared as pure virtual. Does it make the Base class non-abstract? Does a Derived class still have to provide an implementation?

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    ~Base();

    virtual void abstractMethod() = 0;

private:
    uint32_t data;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived();
    ~Derived();
};

void Base::abstractMethod() { data = 1; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Implementing a pure virtual function doesn't change the rules. The function is still pure, the class is still abstract, and a derived class must still override it with a non-pure function, which must be implemented.

If a pure function has an implementation, then it can be called non-virtually:

```
object.Base::abstractMethod();
```

This can be useful if there's a common implementation (or partial implementation) that some derived classes might want to use; they can simply implement their override to call that implementation.